# MongoDB group by multiple child collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

My mongo `User` collection have three child documents

```
   /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1.0,
    "FreeRegistrations" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1.0,
            "Code" : "1MM"
        }
    ],
    "PaidRegistrations" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 2.0,
            "Code" : "1MM"
        }
    ],
    "CustomRegistrations" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 3.0,
            "Code" : "1MM"
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 2.0,
    "FreeRegistrations" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 4.0,
            "Code" : "2MM"
        }
    ],
    "PaidRegistrations" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 5.0,
            "Code" : "1MM"
        }
    ],
    "CustomRegistrations" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 6.0,
            "Code" : "3MM"
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 3.0,
    "FreeRegistrations" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 7.0,
            "Code" : "1MM"
        }
    ],
    "PaidRegistrations" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 8.0,
            "Code" : "2MM"
        }
    ],
    "CustomRegistrations" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 9.0,
            "Code" : "1MM"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to get all user registration counts by code. So from above collection I want result like this:

```
 Code      Count (Number of users)
 1MM                  3
 2MM                  2 
 3MM                  1
```

Please advice some way to use group on multiple child collection

(Robo 3T 1.2.1) (MongoDB.Driver 2.4.4)

Answer (score 0):

There could be many ways to do this but the basic concept is you have to union the registrations, group them by user and then group them by code.

So this should work for you:

```
db.user.aggregate([
   {
      $project:{
         userId:"$_id",
         registrations:{
            $setUnion:[
               "$FreeRegistrations",
               "$PaidRegistrations",
               "$CustomRegistrations"
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $unwind:"$registrations"
   },
   {
      $group:{
         _id:{
            userId:"$userId",
            code:"$registrations.Code"
         },
         userId:{
            $first:"$userId"
         },
         code:{
            $first:"$registrations.Code"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $group:{
         _id:{
            code:"$code"
         },
         Code:{
            $first:"$code"
         },
         "Count (Number of users)":{
            $sum:1
         },

      }
   }
])
```

The output:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "code" : "2MM"
    },
    "Code" : "2MM",
    "Count (Number of users)" : 2.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "code" : "3MM"
    },
    "Code" : "3MM",
    "Count (Number of users)" : 1.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "code" : "1MM"
    },
    "Code" : "1MM",
    "Count (Number of users)" : 3.0
}
```

Comment: $setUnion is only available in version >= 2.6 of mongodb

Comment: i m using an old version of mongo 2.4 and $setUnion is not there

Comment: hmm... let me think about it

Comment: 2.4 is very old :) you cant also use $unwind

Comment: @AnilD Is it mongodb v2.4, or driver v2.4? mongo 2.4 was decommissioned 2 years ago. Driver 2.4 works well with mongodb versions up to 3.4.

Comment: @dsharew MongoDB v2.4 have `$unwind` (http://www.dba86.com/docs/mongo/2.4/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind.html#pipe._S_unwind)

Comment: Not sure it is saying 'MongoDB shell version: 3.0.14', And MongoDB.Driver\2.4.4

Comment: @AnilD shell is a different thing. If it is a local setup, it's likely you have db v3.0 as well, but if database is remote, the version can be different. You can find db version by executing `db.version()` in the mongo shell. It's recommended to develop against the same version of the db that you have in production.

Comment: then you have $setUnion =)

Comment: but i m getting 'errmsg: exception: invalid operator '$setUnion',

`db.runCommand( {
    aggregate: "User",
    pipeline: [
    {$project:{ userId:"$_id", registrations:{
            $setUnion:["$FreeRegistrations","$PaidRegistrations","$CustomRegistrations"]}}},
    {$unwind:"$registrations"},
    {$group:{_id:{userId:"$userId",code:"$registrations.Title"},
            userId:{$first:"$userId"},
            code:{$first:"$registrations.Title"}}},
    {$group:{_id:{code:"$code"},Code:{$first:"$code"},"Count (Number of users)":{$sum:1}}}
 ]} )`

Comment: And this
`MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Command aggregate failed: exception: invalid operator '$setUnion'.
  Source=MongoDB.Driver.Core`

Comment: @AnilD can you send me direct download link for mongo 3.0.15?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection("user").aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $project: {
                Registration: {
                    $concatArrays: ["$FreeRegistrations", "$PaidRegistrations", "$CustomRegistrations"]
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$Registration",
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    code: '$Registration.Code'
                },
                ids: {
                    $addToSet: '$_id'
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 4
        {
            $project: {
                code: '$_id.code',
                total_users: {
                    $size: '$ids'
                },
                _id: 0
            }
        },

    ]



);
```

Comment: Rubin, i m getting error `exception: invalid operator '$concatArrays''`